# Relooping the list

Tags: list, python-2.7, loops

Suppose there is a `list = ['A', 'B', 'C']`

And suppose that you need to return `list[1]` item, but the index that you are given is `7`. I.e. If you continually count the items in the list from left to right you end up with `'B'` using `7`. What are the ways to loop through the list in such a way that the loop starts counting from beginning when it hits the end?

I have implemented the modulo logic to return the desired item for now (`7 % 3`), but would be interested in seeing how to actually loop through the list as explained above.

Comment: Just use modulo, like, `list[7 % len(list)]`? Or do you actually need to loop?

Comment: @tobias_k yeap. Looping required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could just do the modulo operation in a loop:

```
lst = ['A', 'B', 'C']
index = 7
for i in range(index + 1):
    print i, lst[i % len(lst)]
```

Or use [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) to cycle through the list until you get to the index:

```
cycled = itertools.cycle(lst)
for i in range(index + 1):
    print i, next(cycled)
```

You could also `zip` that list with a `range` up to and including the index:

```
for i, x in zip(range(index + 1), itertools.cycle(lst)):
    print i, x
```

Another possibility would be to combine `cycle` with `islice`; this way, you can also determine the start position:

```
>>> list(itertools.islice(itertools.cycle(["A","B","C"]), 2, 7))
['C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A']
```

Comment: I will inspect the code now. I suppose by tweaking the above, I can make it loop in reverse too?

Comment: How exactly do you want to reverse it? Should it go `c, b, a, c, ..., b` or `b, a, c, ..., a`? Try either `reversed(zip(range(...), cycle(lst)))` or `zip(range(...), cycle(reversed(lst)))`

Comment: Given a start index, say [1], so that we start at b, and given number of iterations, say 7, we end up at a (we do not count b).

Comment: I think I have a solution for that. I just create a list in the reverse order and use your code above. Oh, did not notice your answer. Thanks

Comment: can I specify for next(cycled), an index where to start to cycle from?

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal You can use `islice`. See my edit.